# How to adjust borders for an animated container in real time with ontap

Tags: flutter, animation, flutter-animation

Is it possible to remove borders on animated containers in real time with ontap ? By default no borders should be shown however when clicked a border should be shown. See code below:

```
 AnimatedContainer(
                              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                              width: isTextOpen ? 180 : 45, height: 30,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(3)),
                              border: Border.all(color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent),
                            ),
                            child: isTextOpen ?

                                TextField(

                                )
                                : GestureDetector(
                              onTap: (){
                                setState(() {
                                  isTextOpen=true;
                                });
                              },
                              child: Text(
                                "User_002",
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `border` to `null` if a certain condition is not met and give it a `border` if a certain condition is met.

I added a demo using your code as an example:

```
AnimatedContainer(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      width: isTextOpen ? 180 : 45,
      height: 30,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(3)),
        // give it border based on a condition
        border: isTextOpen ? Border.all(color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent, width: 3.0,) : null , // new line
      ),
      child: isTextOpen
          ? TextField()
          : GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  isTextOpen = true;
                });
              },
              child: Text(
                "User_002",
              ),
            ),
    );
```

Comment: At first, I don't want to see any border around objects( User_002) When clicked on it(animated container) I want to expand which I already did. And takes border when it expanded. I tried the demo but nothing occurs. Thanks,

Comment: Might be because the `border` wasn't given a `width`, I updated my question to give the `border` a `width`.

Comment: Now, from the beginning bigger border spawns

Comment: You just need to change how the `ternary` operator is structured. May I ask a question, if the `isTextOpen` is `true`, the border should be visible yeah ?

Comment: Exactly... I am a little bit beginner is it this?  // bool isTextOpen = false;

Comment: I updated my answer to only show the border if the `isTextOpen` is `true`. The border will not be visible if `isTextOpen` is `false`.

Comment: I already tried to do that I accept the question as an answer. However, the system says that I need 15 reps for that action.